# Delete all record from MySQL database using play framework java

Tags: java, playframework

How to delete all the record from database using ebean ORM Model. To delete a single record i am using the code below

```
Book book = Book.find.byId(id);

if(book == null)
{
    return notFound("Book not found");
}

book.delete();

return ok(Json.toJson(book));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming in `Book`, you have somewhere a full `List` of books.

Therefore, you can loop through the full list and delete them.

```
for (Book book : books) {
    book.delete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its working fine. Can we delete all books with out using any loop ?

Comment: Not terribly sure, I imagine you could drop the table and recreate it and therefore it will be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Ebean have 'deleteAll' method to delete collection. I will also suggest transaction management.

```
try{
    List<Book> books = Book.find.where().eq("to_delete",true).findList();
    Ebean.beginTransaction();

    Ebean.deleteAll(books);

    Ebean.commitTransaction();
}catch(Exception e){
    Ebean.endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have decided to delete all records from the table you can [Truncate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncate_(SQL)) the table, which will delete all the records from the table and only the table structure remains left. Truncating the table is much cleaner way in terms of removing each record in a collection sequentially.

Comment: How do I truncate with ebean?